# How to resume auto focus on Google Hangout

Tags: google-plus

When I start a Google Hangout, the video is auto focusing with the person talking. But once I click on just one of the person's video, it just focuses on that person. I want it to return to the auto focus video mode again. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just click on the focused person's video again to return to auto focusing.

Comment: Note that if one participant is sharing their screen, the focus will still switch to them even when they're not speaking and you've de-selected your explicit focus.